# finding a div parent element with a certain property

Tags: jquery

When my slider moves I have to catch the id of the div containing data-role="page"

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="buttons"> 
   <div data-role="content"> 
    <label for="slider1">Slider 1</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="0" min="0" max="100"  /> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

And then when the slider event triggers I execute this:

```
console.log($(this).find("div").filter('[data-role=page]').attr("id"));
```

but doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `this`? Is `this` the slider? or the div with data role? If it is the slider, you could try `.closest()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.closest` if `this` is a child of the `div` you want:

```
console.log($(this).closest('div[data-role="page"]').attr("id"));
```